# The nonnegative set of compact subset of $L^p$ is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, compactness

Let $K \subset L^p([0,1])$. Let $f^+(x):= \max\{0,f(x)\}$, for all $x \in [0,1]$, be non-negative part of $f(x)$. Show that the subset of $K$, denoted by $K^+ =\{f^+: f \in K\}$ is also compact.

I am presenting my attempt to prove this question, and looking for comments or verifying.

**My attempt**

Let $\{f^+_n\}$ be a sequence in $K^+$. Then, there exists $\{f_n\}$ in $K$ such that $f^+_n(x) = \max\{0,f(x)\}$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Since $K$ is compact, then there exists $\{f_{n_k}\}$ in $K$ and $f \in L^p ([0,1])$ such that $\|f_{n_k}-f\|_p \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$. Define $f^-(x) := \min \{  0, f(x)\}$. Then we have $f= f^+ - f^-$ (I am not sure of this)

$$\|f^+_{n_k} - f^+\| \leq \|f_{n_k} -f \|_p \to 0 \,\,\, \text{ as } \,\,\, k \to \infty.$$

Comment: The splitting into non-negative and non-positive part is no problem. How do you get the last inequality? Proof is fine.

Comment: For two numbers $a$ and $b$ we have $|a^+-b^+|\le |a-b|.$ Indeed $a^+={1\over 2}(a+|a|).$ Hence $|a^+-b^+|\le {1\over 2}|a-b|+{1\over 2}||a|-|b||\le |a-b|.$

Comment: Observe that for any real number $a$, $a^+ = (a+|a|)/2$. Can you use this to prove the last part?

Comment: There is a simpler explanation: the absolute value of the inclination of the graphs of the functions $f(x)=x^+$ and $g(x)=x^-$ is not greater than $1.$ Hence they satisfy the Lipschitz condition with the constant $1.$